# How can I add a custom attribute to an address in Magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to add a custom attribute to addresses to determine whether the address is a home address or not.  The attribute needs to be a boolean that's required when creating/updating an address, and it needs to appear with the other address information in the various views.  I'll be using this to figure out whether or not to charge tax based on if it's a home address or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the Magento wiki:
[Magento Wiki Add Custom Field Address](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/how_to_add_custom_field_in_billing_and_shipping_address_in_frontend_and_backend)

Try this too.

```
'input' => 'select',
'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
```

Comment: I checked that out already but I specifically need information about the select type.  I've got something in place but I get:
Source model "" not found for attribute "address_location_type"